How do I verify that Virtual Threads are being used in my Spring Boot microservice?
Libraries used by my microservice, running on JDK 21

Spring Boot 3.4.1
Spring Cloud 2024.0.0
Spring Cloud AWS 3.3.0-RC1

I have set spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true in my Spring Boot microservice, and I am using a RestClient to make an HTTP call to another microservice. When I look at logs generated when this call is made, they look like the following:
undertow-50      | DEBUG | o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient

In this example, the thread name is undertow-50, which to me looks like it's running on a platform thread and not a Virtual Thread.
How can I verify that Virtual Threads are being used? Is there more that I need to code or configure to get them enabled?

Try setting your logger level to TRACE. See if more information shows up. The "undertow-x" on your log comes from the Undertow web server which is likely your application is using. It is defined by the thread pool that is associated by the task running. Unfortunately I don't think there is an automated way out of the box way for you to see that. Best I can think of is you can implement a logger aspect and check whether the thread running is virtual or not.

One of the easiest ways that I had used in a similar situation was to add a controller endpoint that used to log Thread.curentThread().toString() and the output would have been something like VirtualThread(#131, tomcat-handler-3]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4 for virtual thread enabled and Thread[#135, http-nio-88080-exec-2,5,main] without it.

Could you post relevant parts of your pom/Undertow configuration files here or get an MRE somewhere on GitHub or the like? Support of virtual threads might be in places limited at this point of time and I am not sure how Undertow handles this.

If you can "get inside" of this Undertow thread, i.e. change the source code which is executed by this thread or somehow instrument this code, then the best way is to call Thread.currentThread().isVirtual().

These are some great ideas. At this point, I think I'm going to wrap RestClient with an Aspect that logs out the thread and tests whether it's virtual.

Yes, this should work as well. I'd say annotate your @Service method with @Async, but you know the best. You may loose, however, the ThreadLocals that might be bound to Undertow-provided, HTTP request-handling thread, e.g. Spring Security, Micrometer Tracing, MDC, if you have ones. So, it still might be better to make Undertow to run virtual threads. How do you configure Undertow? By including org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow dependency?

Yes, I include that dependency and exclude the default tomcat one. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.4-Release-Notes#virtual-threads. Virtual Threads are now supported in Undertow as of Spring Boot 3.4.0.

Based on the ideas in the comments, I created an @Aspect around the code that calls RestClient that logs out the thread name and tests whether the thread is a virtual thread.
Here's the code and output of those logs, verifying that the thread is virtual.
log.debug("Here's the thread name: {}", Thread.currentThread());
log.debug("Is it a virtual thread?: {}", Thread.currentThread().isVirtual());

2024-12-31 | 12:14:50.160 | undertow-22      | DEBUG | Here's the thread name: VirtualThread[#96,undertow-22]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
2024-12-31 | 12:14:50.160 | undertow-22      | DEBUG | Is it a virtual thread?: true


From your log and from what you said in the comments it looks like that it is Undertow thread that logs these two records, not an @Async-managed thread. Have you enabled @Async, e.g. by annotating  @EnableAsync some @Configuration class? But I believe that if Undertow gives you virtual threads it is unnecessary  (and even potentially harmful, due to ThreadLocals). I'd suggest to remove @Async and see if the thread is still virtual.

I never added @Async to get the answer I posted, so you are right, it is unnecessary.
